# python: what is best way to check multiple keys exists in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

my dict looks like

```
d = {
  'name': 'name',
  'date': 'date',
  'amount': 'amount',
  ...
}
```

I want to test if `name` and `amount` exists, so I will do

```
if not `name` in d and not `amount` in d:
  raise ValueError # for example
```

Suppose I get the data from an api and I want to test if `10` of the fields exists in the dictionary or not.

Is it still the best way to look for?

Comment: Obviously rather late, but I assume the logic you want is `if name not in d or amount not in d: raise ValueError` (`or`, not `and`). Using `and`, you only raise an exception if *both* are missing, but the program logic would seem to support raising an exception if *either* is missing. If `and` is correct, there is a better solution than what you've got.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `set` intersections:

```
if not d.viewkeys() & {'amount', 'name'}:
    raise ValueError
```

In Python 3, that'd be:

```
if not d.keys() & {'amount', 'name'}:
    raise ValueError
```

because `.keys()` returns a dict view by default. [Dictionary view objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) such as returned by `.viewkeys()` (and `.keys()` in Python 3) act as sets and intersection testing is very efficient.

Demo in Python 2.7:

```
>>> d = {
...   'name': 'name',
...   'date': 'date',
...   'amount': 'amount',
... }
>>> not d.viewkeys() & {'amount', 'name'}
False
>>> del d['name']
>>> not d.viewkeys() & {'amount', 'name'}
False
>>> del d['amount']
>>> not d.viewkeys() & {'amount', 'name'}
True
```

Note that this tests True only if *both* keys are missing. If you need your test to pass if *either* is missing, use:

```
if not d.viewkeys() >= {'amount', 'name'}:
    raise ValueError
```

which is False only if *both* keys are present:

```
>>> d = {
...   'name': 'name',
...   'date': 'date',
...   'amount': 'amount',
... }
>>> not d.viewkeys() >= {'amount', 'name'}
False
>>> del d['amount']
>>> not d.viewkeys() >= {'amount', 'name'})
True
```

For a *strict* comparison (allowing *only* the two keys, no more, no less), in Python 2, compare the dictionary view against a set:

```
if d.viewkeys() != {'amount', 'name'}:
    raise ValueError
```

(So in Python 3 that would be `if d.keys() != {'amount', 'name'}`).

Comment: I am confused a bit, how can I test if `{'amount', 'name'}` both are present in `d`?

Comment: @daydreamer: `d.viewkeys() >= {'amount', 'name'}` is `True` if both keys are present.

Comment: I needed strict comparison, so I believe `>>> d.viewkeys() == {'name', 'amount', 'date'}
True` is good enough, what do you think?

Comment: @daydreamer: then you don't need a dict view; updated the answer to show what to do for a strict comparison.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Shouldnt the strict comparison have a set on RHS?

Comment: @Moberg: in Python 2, `dict.keys()` produces a list, so equality tests must use a list on the RHS.

Comment: @Moberg: in Python 3, yes, use a set.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But the comparison with the list (in python2 case) has the drawback that you don't know in which order the keys will be listed.

Comment: @Moberg good point!  I’ll check if a viewkeys comparison is a better option. Otherwise you’d ha e to convert to a set.

Comment: @Moberg: thanks again, not sure why I missed that important detail.

Answer (score 11):

```
if all(k not in d for k in ('name', 'amount')):
    raise ValueError
```

or

```
if all(k in d for k in ('name', 'amount')):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Easier to read and cross compatible with every python version. +1.

Answer (score 5):

You also could use set as:

```
>>> d = {
  'name': 'name',
  'date': 'date',
  'amount': 'amount',
}
>>> test = set(['name','date'])
>>> test.issubset(set(d.keys()))
True
```

Comment: If you are using a `set` method you don't need to convert the argument to `set`. so `test.issubset(d.keys())` will work fine. You can simplify this further and do `test.issubset(d)` Alternatively `test` <= `d.viewkeys()` (or `d.keys()` on Py3k). I would +1 this if I didn't run out of votes

Comment: `{'name','date'}.issubset(d.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

I like this form:

```
>>> d = {
...   'name': 'name',
...   'date': 'date',
...   'amount': 'amount'
... }
>>> tests={'name','date'}
>>> if any(test not in d for test in tests):
...    raise ValueError
>>> # no error...

>>> del d['name']
>>> if any(test not in d for test in tests):
...    raise ValueError
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError
```

Works on Py 2 or Py 3

Answer (score 0):

For maximum efficiency, you want to avoid constructing unnecessary temporary `set`s (which all the non-comparison binary operators require). You can do this for:

```
if name not in d and amount not in d:
```

with:

```
if d.keys().isdisjoint(("amount", "name")):
```

but that's likely the wrong logic (in both cases), since it only enters the `if` body (and raises the exception) when *both* keys are missing, and you likely want to raise the exception if *either* key is missing.

For the more likely intended logic of rejecting `d` unless it contains *both* keys, you'd want this:

```
if name not in d or amount not in d:
```

which can be done with set operations this way:

First, you'd predefine (outside the function to avoid repeated construction of a set):

```
required_keys = frozenset({"amount", "name"})
```

then do:

```
if not d.keys() >= required_keys:
```

Both solutions (`isdisjoint` and `>=`) avoid constructing per test temporaries sets, and should operate as efficiently as possible (short-circuiting as soon as a single key is found to be missing, and only needing a pair of `O(1)` lookups when both keys are present). Personally, for just two keys, I'd stick with `if name not in d or amount not in d:`, but if the number of keys grows, sure, use set-like operations.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if `name` and `amount` are in the dictionary you have to use a different condition, for example

```
if not ('name' in d and 'amount' in d):
   raise ValueError # for example
```

that is checking that all keys are present. Using only the intersection you get the common keys, to know if all are present in the dictionary the lenght of the intersection has to be checked as well.

This is done in the function 'dictHasAllKeys' of this sample (Python 3) code

```
def dictCommonKeys (dicobj, keylist):
    return keylist & dicobj.keys()
       
def dictHasAllKeys (dicobj, keylist):
    return len (keylist & dicobj.keys()) == len(keylist)
    
keys = [ "name", "amount" ]

d1 = { "name": 1, "date": 2, "amount": 4 }
d2 = { "name": 1, "date": 2 }

print ("dictCommonKeys d1 " + str(dictCommonKeys(d1, keys)))
print ("dictCommonKeys d2 " + str(dictCommonKeys(d2, keys)))
print ("dictHasAllKeys d1 " + str(dictHasAllKeys(d1, keys)))
print ("dictHasAllKeys d2 " + str(dictHasAllKeys(d2, keys)))
```

that outputs

```
  dictCommonKeys d1 {'amount', 'name'}
  dictCommonKeys d2 {'name'}
  dictHasAllKeys d1 True
  dictHasAllKeys d2 False
```