# Make sure that there are two values in a Dictionaries Key Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple dictionary. I am able to check if one value is true. My problem arises when I need to check if two are correct. I want it to return false if one of the two are correct. But it returs True in this case

```
mydict = {}
mydict['Car'] = ['Diesel','Hatchback','2,ltr']
mydict['Bri'] = ['Hatchback','2ltr']


print(mydict.get('Car'))

if 'Diesel'  in mydict.get('Car'):
    print('Found')
else:
    print('This is false')

if 'Diesel' and 'Hatchback' in mydict.get('Bri'):# Here it needs these two values to be true.
    print('Found')
else:
    print('This is false')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: what is best way to check multiple keys exists in a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004593/python-what-is-best-way-to-check-multiple-keys-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not being evaluated the way you think it is:

```
'Diesel' and 'Hatchback' in mydict.get('Bri')
```

But like this

```
'Diesel' and ('Hatchback' in mydict.get('Bri'))
```

So `'Diesel'` evaluates to `True` and the second part too.

What you want is something like this:

```
data = mydict.get('Bri')
if 'Diesel' in data and 'Hatchback' in data:
    ...
```

PS: Although this question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004593/python-what-is-best-way-to-check-multiple-keys-exists-in-a-dictionary) as marked above, the answers there are way more complex than needed for this simple case